# bind listview items from sqlite database to cardview

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, android-cardview

Is there a way to make every list item display on a cardview? This is what i tried so far and when debugging I get the list items but I cant get them to show on the cardview:
This is my adapter code:

```
    public class Item_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
   DBHelper mDbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(context);
List<ItemsHolder> list ;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;



    public Item_adapter(Context context, List list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.items_list,parent,false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.ItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Item_name);
        viewHolder.ItemDescrip = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Item_Description);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        return convertView;
    }
    private static class ViewHolder {

        TextView ItemName;
        TextView ItemDescrip;
    }
}
```

and this is where I call it on the main activity:

mydb = new DBHelper(this);

```
listlist = mydb.getAllItems();
```

// ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
    adapter = new Item_adapter(getApplicationContext(),listlist);

```
obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
obj.setAdapter(adapter);
obj.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ItemsHolder itemsHolder = (ItemsHolder)arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
        int id_To_Search = itemsHolder.Id;

        Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
        dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DsiplayItems.class);

        intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: the simplest way is to use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and not `ArrayAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`CursorAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html). It's designed for binding DB rows to [`ListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) rows.

Further, you'll use a [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) to load and manage the cursor within your activity.

Answer (score 0):

In your class you should have reference to your listView and create a CursorAdapter type field so that you can reference them later in the code.
your CursorAdapter class should look like as the following.

```
public class CursorListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public CursorNoticeListAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, null, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // generate your view here and use viewholder pattern

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // here you have viewHolder and the cursor from the database, now just bind them to views
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        // your viewHolder class
        public ViewHolder() {
        }
    }
}
```

then where you query the database, implements this `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`. As you implement this you would have to implement the following methods and initialize the loader in your constructor.

```
public <Your-Class> () {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // this is where you query the database, which shoild give you back a cursor
    // now just create the CursorLoader and return it 
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), URI, PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}


@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

hope you will get your answer